# what exactly does the `--save_resume` option in vowpal wabbit do

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I'm training a neural net with data streamed from two separate sources, heuristically:

```
cat train1.vw |vw --oaa 10 --nn 20 --save_resume -f /tmp/weights
cat train2.vw |vw --oaa 10 --nn 20 --save_resume -i /tmp/weights -f /tmp/weights
```

However this raises an error to the effect that "--oaa cannot be passed multiple times." Fine, `--save_resume` holds on to config arguments, so I revised:

```
cat train1.vw |vw --oaa 10 --nn 20 --save_resume -f /tmp/weights
cat train2.vw |vw --save_resume -i /tmp/weights -f /tmp/weights
```

and everything worked. Out of curiosity I repeated the second approach without the `--save_resume` option, everything *still* worked, except that the model performance was slightly worse.

I would speculate that `--save_resume` saves the learning rate and number of examples seen in the weights file. This is what appeared to be happening from the output, and corroborates better performance. Is there anything else?

**Edit:** After a little experimentation I see that passing the initial regressor via `-i` is what raises the "option '--oaa' cannot be specified more than once error," not `--save_resume`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your speculation is correct. When not using `--save_resume` with the first training on `train1.vw`, the model `/tmp/weights` does not contain learning rate and other state information (e.g. `--adaptive` is used by default in VW, so there is a learning rate for each feature). This may influence the quality of the final model, usually it makes it worse.

Another reason for the different number reported as *average loss* is that when not using `--save_resume`, VW computes the average only for the given data (`train1.vw` resp. `train2.vw`).

The idea of `--save_resume` is that you should get the same final *average loss* when training in two steps

```
cat train1.vw | vw --oaa 10 --nn 20 --save_resume -f /tmp/weights
cat train2.vw | vw --save_resume -i /tmp/weights -f /tmp/weights
```

and when training in one step

```
cat train1.vw train2.vw | vw --oaa 10 --nn 20 -f /tmp/weights
```

See a [related solved GitHub issue](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/issues/262).

Comment: +1 for the link to the issue on GitHub. I completely agree with your expectations about the "expected behavior" of `--save_resume` in training versus just test mode.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there was a bug introduced recently here, I logged a ticket for it:
https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/issues/554

Update: They already fixed it in master. So make sure to pull.